# SwiftUI - Inconsistent data for two diferent subviews inside a ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm building an app which makes graphs and calculates some basic stuff. On the main screen, I have a ForEach loop inside a List that shows the saved charts. When entering the NavigationLink inside the List, the destination view does not correspond with the label shown (video below).

I had to use a custom ForEach extension to deal with the bindings https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/ (Apple announced that on iOS 15 ForEach will accept bindings, but I'm developing for iOS 14).

The code of the List:

```
List{
    ForEach($chartData.calibrations) { index, data in
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailedChartView(index: index, currentData: data, isDetailShown: $detailVisible),
                isActive: $detailVisible,
                label: {
                    SavedListItem(index: index, savedData: self.chartData.calibrations[index])
                })
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }.onDelete(perform: removeRows)
}.id(UUID())
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

The code of the label (SavedListItem)

```
struct SavedListItem: View {
    
    var index: Int
    
    var data: ChartDataObject
    
    var formattedSlope = ""
    
    var formattedOrigin = ""
    
    var formattedCoef = ""
    
    init(index: Int, savedData: ChartDataObject) {
        
        self.data = savedData
        self.index = index
        
        self.formattedSlope = String(format: "%.2f", data.slope)
        self.formattedOrigin = String(format: "%.2f", abs(data.origin))
        self.formattedCoef = String(format: "%.3f", data.regressionCoef)
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Text("\(index + 1)").bold()
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 10) {
                Text("\(data.name)").font(.title3)
                Text("\(formatDate(data.date))")
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
            if data.origin > 0 {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("y = \(self.formattedSlope)x + \(formattedOrigin)")
                        Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                        Text("R2 = \(formattedCoef)")
                    }
                }
            }
            else if data.origin == 0 {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("y = \(formattedSlope)x")
                        Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                        Text("R2 = \(formattedCoef)")
                    }
                }
            }
            else if data.origin < 0 {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("y = \(formattedSlope)x - \(formattedOrigin)")
                        Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                        Text("R2 = \(formattedCoef)")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Text("There was an error")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
    private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        
        return dateString
    }
    
}
```

And the code of DetailedChartView:

```
struct DetailedChartView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var calibrationsController: SavedCalibrationsController
    
    var index: Int
    
    @Binding var currentData: ChartDataObject
    
    var copyData: ChartDataObject {
        return currentData
    }
            
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false
    
    @Binding var isDetailShown: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("y = \(currentData.origin) + \(currentData.slope)x")
                Text("Slope: \(currentData.slope)")
                Text("Origin: \(currentData.origin)")
                Text("R2: \(currentData.regressionCoef)")
                
                Divider()
                
                RegressionChart(data: currentData).frame(height: 500)
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(currentData.name)
        .toolbar(content: {
            Button(action: {
                self.isEditing = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Edit")
            })
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isEditing, onDismiss: {
            currentData = copyData
            calibrationsController.saveData()
            isEditing = false
            isDetailShown = false
        }, content: {
            EditView(calibrationsController: calibrationsController, editVisible: $isEditing, isDetailShown: $isDetailShown, index: index, data: $currentData).environmentObject(calibrationsController)
        })
    }
}
```

When there is only one item the List behaves as expected.

[image: Gif]

This issue is driving me nuts: if I use a List (without the ForEach), everything works as expected but I cant change the ForEach because I lose the .onDelete() functionality, and deleting the items inside the detailed view (which has an edit button), gives me an index out of range error (another story...).

Sorry for the long post!

EDIT: Minimal reproductible example

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WN_tGR_kVNVNqEOW054d6kMBlq8HGkF5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you create a [mre] that can be copied and pasted into Xcode? No one can test what you have here because it depends on custom types/code not included in your example.

Comment: Added a link! Thnaks, I'm new to programming and I didn't know about the existence of minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: A link to the whole project is okay, but it's unlikely that someone is going to download it from a separate site and try to parse through all of the code to find your issue. In a [mre], the idea is to remove all of the unnecessary information that doesn't relate to the issue. For example, with your issue, there's no need to include *any* of the chart stuff, any of the sheets, etc -- include only enough to show the actual issue. A potential upside is that you may solve your own issue in the process, since it involves really looking at all of your code to find out what relates.

Comment: Then, ideally, you'd copy-and-paste that [mre] here, since links to other sites can go stale over time. Here's an example of a good minimal example from a post from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172249/update-text-with-slider-value-in-list-from-an-array-in-swiftui

Comment: I noticed you have 2 NavigationView, one in MainList, fair enough, 
but then you have one more in DetailedChartView. 
Try to reorganise the code to have just the one NavigationView in MainList,
ie remove the one in DetailedChartView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
isActive: $detailVisible,
```

in MainList NavigationLink.

Comment: Wow... That worked but now I question: how do I dismiss de view programatically?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. To dismiss the view programmatically, well maybe just use a different variable.